# Firebase realtime database I can't change data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This problem just started to occur. The problem is when I change data on the firebase console it won't let me make changes. When I try to change data on the app it enters a perfect bug. The data that I change updates itself rapidly and goes back to its original state and this continues continuously. The database started to be updated all the time and I added write false to the security rules and now the updates stopped.

This problem only occurs when I change the data in the node I marked in the picture.

Users=>UserId=>forms=>formId
https://prnt.sc/vp2lbb

```
Before
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":"auth!=null",
        ".write":"auth!=null"
  }
}

After
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":"auth!=null",
        ".write":"false"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my cloud function :

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    var now = new Date
    admin.database().ref("/forms").orderByKey().once("value",snap=>{snap.forEach(a=>{
      var x =new Date(a.child("endDate").val()).getTime()
      if(x-now<0){
       admin.database().ref('/users/'+a.child("who").val()+"/forms/"+a.key).update({
          update : false
        })
      admin.database().ref('/forms/'+a.key+"/participants/").once("value",c=>c.forEach(uid=>{
          admin.database().ref('/users/'+uid.key+'/participateCamp/'+a.key).remove()
        })).then(()=>admin.database().ref('/forms/'+a.key).remove())
        
      }
          
      }
     )})
 
  return null;
});
```

There's also another table called **forms**:https://prnt.sc/vp3pjj

The form of a user who opens a form is added to both the form table and Users=>UserId=>forms=>formId

**SOLVED**

I noticed that this problem started when I updated the form in the application.When I updated, I noticed that valueChanges () was triggered and I didn't unsubscribe()

So the problem was caused by the code I wrote.Maybe friends who encounter this kind of problem will see it and pay attention to their valueCahnges() methods.

Comment: If you think the answer may be useful for another user, please post it as an answer - instead of as an update to the question. In its current form, I'm not convinced as I have a feeling we're not seeing the code that caused the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ı posted answer. hope it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

Before updateForm function:

```
updateForm(form : FormGroup,formId){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
      if (user) {
        this.db.database.ref('/users/'+user.uid).once("value",snap=>{
          
        })
        this.pp = this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).valueChanges()
        this.pp.forEach(x=>{console.log("neler oluyor")
        this.db.object('/forms/' + formId).update({
           place : form.value.place,
           who : user.uid,
           description:form.value.description,
           startDate : form.value.startDate,
           endDate : form.value.endDate,
           pp : x.pp,
           name : x.name,
           formId : formId,
           chat:{"1":{message:"Form Chat Açıldı!",name:"Sistem"}}
          }).then(x=>this.db.object('/users/'+ user.uid+'/forms/'+formId).update({
            place : form.value.place,
            description:form.value.description,
           startDate : form.value.startDate,
           endDate : form.value.endDate,
           update : true
          })) })
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
  }
```

After I fixed and solved the problem:

```
 updateForm(form : FormGroup,formId){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
      if (user) {
        this.db.database.ref('/users/'+user.uid).once("value",snap=>{
          this.db.object('/forms/' + formId).update({
            place : form.value.place,
            who : user.uid,
            description:form.value.description,
            startDate : form.value.startDate,
            endDate : form.value.endDate,
            pp : snap.child("pp").val(),
            name : snap.child("name").val(),
            formId : formId,
            chat:{"1":{message:"Form Chat Açıldı!",name:"Sistem"}}
           }).then(x=>this.db.object('/users/'+ user.uid+'/forms/'+formId).update({
             place : form.value.place,
             description:form.value.description,
            startDate : form.value.startDate,
            endDate : form.value.endDate,
            update : true
           })) 
        })
      } else {
      }
    });
  }
```